# infinite loop with changing timeouts

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, infinite-loop

I have an array that contains time windows. For a simple case I'm making these 10 second windows as follows, (In the beginning the current time will be inside window 1)

```
var now = new Date();
windowList = [
    { id: 1,
        start: new Date().setSeconds(now.getSeconds() - 5),
        end: new Date().setSeconds(now.getSeconds() + 5),
        waitTime: 2000},
    { id: 2,
        start: new Date().setSeconds(now.getSeconds() + 10),
        end: new Date().setSeconds(now.getSeconds() + 20),
        waitTime: 500}]
```

Then I've setup two functions to check if current time is in a window and in some window.

```
function isInWindow(window){
    var now = new Date();
    return (window.start < now && now < window.end);
}
```

and

```
function isInSomeWindow(windows){
    for (var i = 0; i < windows.length; i++) {
        if(isInWindow(windows[i])){
            return windows[i];
            break;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to go through the windowList as I loop with a period of waitTime. Whenever I'm not in a window I loop with period of 500 ms.

```
function daynmicRepeat() {
    var localPeriod = 1000;
    setTimeout(function () {
        window = isInSomeWindow(windowList);
        if (window){
            console.log('in window ' + window.id + ' @ ' + new Date())
            localPeriod = window.waitTime;
        } else {
            console.log('not in a window @ ' + new Date());
            localPeriod = 500;
        }
        daynmicRepeat();
    },localPeriod);
}
```

when I run it

```
daynmicRepeat()
```

I start off inside the first window and then eventually come out of it but never seem to go in to the 2nd window. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I dont understand what you want to do. But I think that you can do it better with setInterval() .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take another look at the loop in your `isInSomeWindow` function -- it will never get past the first run:

```js
if(isInWindow(windows[i])){
    return windows[i];
    break;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

If `isInWindow(windows[0])` returns false, you hit the `else` statement, and return out of the function.

Assuming you want the function to return false if no matching window is found, you want to return if the loop finished without returning:

```
function isInSomeWindow(windows){
    for (var i = 0; i < windows.length; i++) {
        if(isInWindow(windows[i])){
            return windows[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`isInSomeWindow` breaks the loop. Try this:

```
function isInSomeWindow(windows){
    for (var i = 0; i < windows.length; i++) {
        if(isInWindow(windows[i])){
            return windows[i];
    }
}
```